# ACPI PCC probe failed during installation of ubuntu 14.04 Lts

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, acpi

I'm try to install ubuntu 14.04 Lts distribution in a machine Dell precision T1700 with Windows 8.1..The  LiveCD shows correctly the options of grub menu but, when I selected any option for installation, the error "ACPI PCC probe failed" appers and the screen keeps black finishing the process.  I already tried with other proposed solutions on tje dame error as ACPI disable motion in the grub menu and modify the graphics options multi-screen on the motherboard. The machine has all the draivers installed and also has a graphics card NVidia quadro K2200. Gread maid who can help me with this difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

When booting - highlight Try Ubuntu without installing - press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

After you completed Ubuntu installation, do the same on first system start.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

First install the NVIDIA drivers - now adding the parameter is unnecessary.